# What does “having a party piece” mean in the following content?

Tags: meaning

> "That style of playing originally came from me and George [Harrison] having a party piece when we were kids, which was a piece by Bach.

Full article http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/4208132.stm

Comment: I'm closevoting for lack of prior research. Googling [define "party piece"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=define+%22party+piece%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) returns many dictionary definitions for this colloquial BrE term.

Comment: Please don't close this question.  As an American, I would have assumed the meaning of this phrase - and been totally wrong.  We say, "bit", as in: "What's your bit?" or, we borrow the Yiddish, "shtick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Party piece:

a poem, song, dance, or trick regularly performed by someone in order to entertain others.

"his party piece is placing a banger between his cheeks and setting it 
off"

Chris can wiggle his ears, it's his party piece!

Ref:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/party-piece

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/party-piece

Comment: Dear Fumblefingers! Like Oldbag, I ask you not to close this question! I think it is a good phrase to know, since I am not familiar with British words that much, I really liked this question! :). please!!!